# Stack Two Lists of Depth=2

Tags: list-manipulation

My question is to combine a matrix of values with a matrix of 2D coordinates:

```
Coor = {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{u, v}, {s, t}}};
Value = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
```

I want to get

```
Combined = {{{a, b,1}, {c, d,2}}, {{u, v,3}, {s, t,4}}};
```

so I can use ListPlot3D

This is similar to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513010/how-to-combine-two-lists-to-plot-coordinate-pairs?rq=1). I attempt to use this solution by doing this

```
MapThread[List, {matrix1, matrix}, 2]
```

But this gives me 
 `{{{{a, b},1}, {{c, d},2}}...};`
which has an extra bracket inside that I couldn't figure out how to remove...

How can I get the desired "Combined" list? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Coor = {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{u, v}, {s, t}}};
Val = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

MapThread[Append, {Coor, Val}, 2]
```

> {{{a, b, 1}, {c, d, 2}}, {{u, v, 3}, {s, t, 4}}}

Also

```
Join[Coor, Map[List, Val, {-1}] , 3]
```

> {{{a, b, 1}, {c, d, 2}}, {{u, v, 3}, {s, t, 4}}}

Answer (score 0):

```
coor = {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{u, v}, {s, t}}};
val = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

Join[coor, Transpose[{val}, {3, 1, 2}], 3]
(* {{{a, b, 1}, {c, d, 2}}, {{u, v, 3}, {s, t, 4}}} *)
```

Or alternatively:

```
Flatten[{Transpose[coor, {2, 3, 1}], {val}}, {{3}, {4}, {1, 2}}]
```